# Why can't output info, debug log？

Tags: testing, logging, python-3.9, cnosdb

I am learning about the logging package, and when outputting log control, I find that it is always impossible to output logs at levels below info.As follow：

```
import logging

logger1 = logging.getLogger("logger1")
print(logger1.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO));

logger1.setLevel(logging.INFO)
print(logger1.isEnabledFor(logging.INFO));

logger1.debug("This is  DEBUG of logger1 !!")
logger1.info("This is  INFO of logger1 !!")
logger1.warning("This is  WARNING of logger1 !!")
logger1.error("This is  ERROR of logger1 !!")
logger1.critical("This is  CRITICAL of logger1 !!")
```

log as follow

```
(venv) ➜  cloud_test python3 testcase/test.py
False
True
This is  WARNING of logger1 !!
This is  ERROR of logger1 !!
This is  CRITICAL of logger1 !!
```

I check the bug level debug,notset,info ,I find that it is always impossible to output logs at levels below info. Is the code has some pro?